# Siri Shortcuts error - I'm trying to run an Applescript that uses "System Events"

Tags: applescript, siri

I'm trying to run an Applescript that centers the window with focus. The shortcut works well, but when I try to use voice command with Siri a "System Event" error occurs, apparently Siri does not have access authorization.

Someone has already seen this problem.

[image: Screenshot showing the error.]

Translation of the error from Portuguese to English: I'm sorry, there was a problem. Shortcuts say: "System Events got a Error: Shortcuts is an assistive access no Allowed."

Comment: If you want help debugging _code_, then you need to include the _code_ in your question so we can copy and paste it without having to manually type it.  That said, do you have **Shortcuts** added to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**?  (Desculpem o inglês pois não falo português.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I had already done this, I even put Siri there too. I'm sure there must be a solution, but so far I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: The code didn't fit here, many characters, but I don't think that's the problem. The code works if I use the button in the Shortcuts application or if I put it in the top bar.

Comment: [I put the Applescript code here](https://luizsiqueiraneto.tumblr.com/post/667483354701135872/applescript-code-to-center-the-focus-window)

Comment: RE: "The code didn't fit here, many characters" --  Just copy and paste it as text from **Shortcuts** as an edit to your question, not on your website as it mangles the _code_ and I'm not going to waste time fixing what you already posted. -- RE: "but I don't think that's the problem. The code works if I use the button in the Shortcuts application or if I put it in the top bar." --  Doesn't matter what the problem is. What matters is being able to test it on my side to see what is what, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

on run {input, parameters}
tell application "Finder"
set screenSize to bounds of window of desktop
set screenWidth to item 3 of screenSize
set screenHeight to item 4 of screenSize
end tell

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell dock preferences
        if screen edge is bottom then
            tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
                set dockSize to size in list 1
                set dockHeight to item 2 of dockSize
                set screenHeight to (screenHeight - dockHeight)
            end tell
        else if screen edge is left then
            tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
                set dockSize to size in list 1
                set dockHeight to item 1 of dockSize
                set screenWidth to (screenWidth + dockHeight)
            end tell
        else
            tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
                set dockSize to size in list 1
                set dockHeight to item 1 of dockSize
                set screenWidth to (screenWidth - dockHeight)
            end tell
        end if
    end tell
    
    set screenHeight to (screenHeight + 22)
    set myFrontMost to name of first item of ¬
        (processes whose frontmost is true)
end tell

try
    tell application myFrontMost
        set windowSize to bounds of window 1
        set windowXl to item 1 of windowSize
        set windowYt to item 2 of windowSize
        set windowXr to item 3 of windowSize
        set windowYb to item 4 of windowSize
        
        set windowWidth to windowXr - windowXl
        set windowHeight to windowYb - windowYt
        
        if myFrontMost is "Terminal" then
            set bounds of window 1 to {¬
                round ((screenWidth - windowWidth) / 2) rounding as taught in school, ¬
                round ((screenHeight - windowHeight) / 2) rounding as taught in school, ¬
                round ((screenWidth + windowWidth) / 2) rounding as taught in school, ¬
                round ((screenHeight + windowHeight) / 2) rounding as taught in school}
        else
            set bounds of window 1 to {¬
                round ((screenWidth - windowWidth) / 2) rounding as taught in school, ¬
                round ((screenHeight - windowHeight) / 2) rounding as taught in school, ¬
                round ((screenWidth + windowWidth) / 2) rounding as taught in school, ¬
                round ((screenHeight + windowHeight) / 2) rounding as taught in school}
        end if
        
        set the result to bounds of window 1
        
    end tell
end try

return input
```

end run

Comment: The first time I tried to paste the code, the site accused me that I had exceeded the character limit. This time that didn't happen.

I had also put the link to the original page where I got the code.